# Three Sum HashMap Approach

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, hashmap, hashtable

Hi I don't understand how the k-loop is constant time. If the array was [4,4,4,4,4,4] and the target was 12, then the number_table[4] = [0,1,2,3,4,5] and then the k loop would iterate five times no? asking itself if i, j and k are all different... This video seems to say otherwise?[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jXZDUdHRbhY&t=499s)

```py
def three_sum(nums, target):
  number_table = {}
  for i in range(len(nums)):
    if nums[i] in number_table.keys():
      number_table[nums[i]].append(i)
    else:
      number_table[nums[i]] = []
  for i in range(len(nums) - 1):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(nums)):
      partial_target = target - nums[i] - nums[j]
      for k in number_table[partial_target]:
        if len(set((i,j,k))) == 3:
          return (nums[i], nums[j], nums[k])
  return None

numbers = [4,4,4,4,4,4]
target = 12
three_sum(numbers, target)
print(three_sum(numbers,target))
```

Comment: I can transcribe the code :D

Comment: Where is the typo? I'll try to make this easier for people to compile and write I was looking for a runtime analysis but I will try to make it easier for everyone to answer

Answer (score 2):

When you get to that innermost loop, there are three cases:

- `k == i` ← This can only happen once, because `i` can only appear once in the list.
- `k == j` ← This can only happen once, because `j` can only appear once in the list.
- `k != i and k != j` ← This can only happen once, because you return as soon as it happens. (N.B. The code actually checks if *all three* of `i`, `j`, and `k` are distinct; but we already know that `i != j` because `j` starts at `i + 1` and goes up, so this is equivalent to just checking for `k != i and k != j`.)

So we try at most three values of `k`; and 3 is indeed a constant, as desired.

Comment: @ruakh I think it's time to update your profile. It looks up to date.